# Do you really have to say "かれ" (3rd person pronoun) here?

Tags: translation, pronouns

The context is that *A*, *B*, and *C* just got home. They are now wandering around a big house looking for a group of kids. The 3 are wondering if the kids have been studying. *A* has not yet talked with *C*:

> [line 1]「本当ですか？勉強していますか？」A-さんはたずねた。「証拠は？」
>   [line 2] 「C-さんが見ました」B-さんはいった。「勉強していると**かれが**いうなら、それが立派な証拠だと思いますが」

Part of line #2 reads:

> ...勉強していると**かれが**いうなら...

Because "**かれ**" is obviously *C*, do you really have to say "**かれ**"?
If you do not say "**かれ**", how does it change the nuance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, it would make little to no sense if 「かれ（が）」 were not said.

B-さん is saying that if it were C-さん(← かれ) who says that he saw the kids studying, it would be a highly trustworthy source of information.  It is almost like saying "if the information came from C-さん ***of all people***".

In other words, the fact that the witness is C-さん this time is being the condition for B-さん to call it a good proof that the kids are studying.

Comment: The "Cさん, of all people," meaning was exactly what was called for in the much much larger context that I could not include. Thanks.